# Cannot load JProfiler agent in linux x64

Tags: java, linux, noclassdeffounderror, jprofiler

Can you advise?

I try to install version 64x and install that one:

https://download-gcdn.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/jprofiler_agent_linux-x86_12_0_2.tar.gz

VM settings:
Min. Heap Size: 1.00G
Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 1.50G
Ergonomics Machine Class: server
Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

```
JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_252-b09) (build 1.8.0_252-b09)
Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.252-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [libc.so.6+0x3507b]  abort+0x23b

Core dump written. Default location: /app/core or core.1

An error report file with more information is saved as:
/app/hs_err_pid1.log
```

```
JProfiler> Protocol version 61
JProfiler> JVMTI version 1.1 detected.
JProfiler> Java 8 detected.
JProfiler> Don't wait for frontend to connect.
JProfiler> 64-bit library
JProfiler> Starting up without initial configuration.
JProfiler> Listening on port: 8849.
JProfiler> Enabling native methods instrumentation.
JProfiler> Can retransform classes.
JProfiler> Can retransform any class.
JProfiler> Native library initialized
JProfiler> VM initialized
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.jprofiler.agent.probe.g.f.<init>(ejt:73)
    at com.jprofiler.agent.probe.u.a(ejt:59)
    at com.jprofiler.agent.probe.u.a(ejt:45)
    at com.jprofiler.agent.Agent.initStatic(ejt:249)
    at com.jprofiler.agent.Agent.<clinit>(ejt:90)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.jprofiler.agent.probe.g.f.<init>(ejt:68)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.jprofiler.agent.probe.ProbeHandler
    at com.jprofiler.agent.probe.g.c.<init>(ejt:50)
    at com.jprofiler.agent.probe.g.c.<init>(ejt:116)
    ... 9 more
java: /home/hannes/buildsys_agent/jprofiler/build/ant/c/src/agent/shared/LiveProfilingSession.cpp:257: void LiveProfiling::comThreadCallback(jvmtiEnv*, JNIEnv*, void*): Assertion `probeHandlerClass' failed.
```

Comment: Can you add the entire command line that you are using to start the JVM?

Comment: Yes: java -agentpath:/app/jprofiler/agent/jprofiler12/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=port=8849,nowait -jar xxx.jar